# Assert self.caps, 'Driver capabilities must be defined' AssertionError: Driver capabilities must be defined

Tags: python, appium, desiredcapabilities

When running the following automation script using gigafox I am faced with the error

`Assert self.caps, 'Driver capabilities must be defined' AssertionError: Driver capabilities must be defined`

This occurs while I am running against a browser or an app. Not sure why. Gigafox replaces appium in this case and should not need to be appium. I have tried Chrome and the package name. Not sure why this shows up after all the different settings I have tried.

````
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import time

from appium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities


GF_USER_NAME = 'admin'
GF_API_KEY = ''
GF_DEVICE_ID = '1edcc865-60d9-4574-b46f-96070af21b8a'
GF_HOST = '192.168.0.162'


# These variables probably don't need change unless you change the app or
# the way you use Appium.

#APP_PACKAGE = 'com.fisglobal.d1amerismobile.sit/com.fisglobal.d1amerismobile.sit.MainActivity'
#APP_ACTIVITY = 'com.fisglobal.d1amerismobile.sit/com.fisglobal.d1amerismobile.sit.MainActivity'

AUTOMATION_NAME = 'UiAutomator2'
#desired_caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME

desired_capabilities = {
    'gigafox:UserName'      : GF_USER_NAME,
    'gigafox:ApiKey'        : GF_API_KEY,
    'gigafox:Device'        : GF_DEVICE_ID,
    'gigafox:application'   : "",
    'appPackage'            : "",
    'appActivity'           : "",
    'browserName'           : "Chrome",
    'newCommandTimeout'     : 20000,
    'platformName'          : "Android",
    'automationName'        : AUTOMATION_NAME
}


#url used to connect to the host server where the device is
url = 'http://{0}/Appium'.format(GF_HOST)
print('loading driver')

#Starts the driver to establish connection to device
driver = webdriver.Remote(url, desired_capabilities)

print('connected.')
time.sleep(10)

#Sets the site the browser will open
driver.get("https://www.appium.io")
print('connected.')
time.sleep(10)

driver.quit()```
````

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3?  I haven't seen `__future__` in quite some time.

Comment: @Makoto this is python 3 but I did have it commented out as well and same issue